# Pushing object into array causes TypeError

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have my `values` object

```
values = {
    'student': [{
        'field': 'prefix',
        'description': 'First name'
    }, {
        'field': 'suffix',
        'description': 'Last name'
    }, {
        'field': 'student_email',
        'description': 'Email address'
    }],
    'classes': [{
        'field': 'course_code',
        'description': 'Course code'
    }]
}
```

And I'm trying to get each object within 'student' and 'classes'. Once grabbed I'm trying to create a new object that looks like this

```
{type:'student', field:'prefix', description:'First Name', key:'school'}
```

and then push that object into a new array. This is what I have so far...

```
const array = [];

for(const v in values) {
    array.concat(values[v].map(obj => {
       console.log(obj); // grabs each obj successfully
       array.push({
           type: v,
           description: obj.description,
           field: obj.field,
           key: 'school'
       });
    });
}
```

Right now its throwing `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`. What am I doing wrong? Can I not create a new object inside of .map()?

Comment: `values` is clearly an ***object***, which has no `Array.concat()` method

Comment: There's no reference to "split" in the code you posted; that can't be where the error is coming from.

Comment: @Pointy lol theres no reference to `split` in my code at all. :\

Comment: @adeneo no but `student` and `classes` are both arrays

Comment: maybe a third party lib?

Comment: @TamasHegedus hmm maybe... but the way im creating of a new array with the new object is correct right?

Comment: And yet, you're getting an error that says `split` is undefined, with a line number and a direct reference to where the error originates from? Note that you're doing `values.concat(...`

Comment: The array.push in the map function makes no sense for me... instead of array.push you should just return the object you try to push !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var values = {'student':[{'field':'prefix','description':'Firstname'},{'field':'suffix','description':'Lastname'},{'field':'student_email','description':'Emailaddress'}],'classes':[{'field':'course_code','description':'Coursecode'}]};

var out = Object.keys(values).map(function(type) {
  return values[type].map(function(item) {
    return {
      name: type,
      field: item.field,
      descriptiom: item.description,
      key: 'school'
    };
  });
}).reduce(function(l, r) {
  return l.concat(r); 
});

console.log(out);
```

---

Or, so much nicer with [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
var out = Object.keys(values).map((type) =>
  values[type].map((item) => ({
    name: type,
    field: item.field,
    descriptiom: item.description,
    key: 'school'
  })
}).reduce((l, r) => l.concat(r));
```

Comment: This is the answer ! Just instead of the map on keys, you can directly use the reduce function ;)

Comment: whoa.. a .map() inside a .map(). isn't that something you'd want to avoid?

Comment: @Modelesq Why would you? That's basically no different from a nested loop. Unless you have very valid reasons to move to a different soultion, this is probably the most readable and maintainable one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like TimoSta said but replacing the first map with reduce :

```js
var values = {'student':[{'field':'prefix','description':'Firstname'},{'field':'suffix','description':'Lastname'},{'field':'student_email','description':'Emailaddress'}],'classes':[{'field':'course_code','description':'Coursecode'}]};

var out = Object.keys(values).reduce(function(previous, type) {
  return previous.concat(values[type].map(function(item) {
    return {
      name: type,
      field: item.field,
      descriptiom: item.description,
      key: 'school'
    };
  }));
}, []);

console.log(out);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for getting all objects in an array.

```js
var values = { 'student': [{ 'field': 'prefix', 'description': 'First name' }, { 'field': 'suffix', 'description': 'Last name' }, { 'field': 'student_email', 'description': 'Email address' }], 'classes': [{ 'field': 'course_code', 'description': 'Course code' }] },
    array = Object.keys(values).reduce((r, k) => 
        r.concat(values[k].map(a =>
            ({ type: k, field: a.field, description: a.description, key: 'school' }))), []);

console.log(array);
```